# How to convert a string to a valid JSON after exploding a string more than one time

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to explode a string more the one time and convert the result to a valid JSON and I cannot figure out the way.

I'm trying to explode and do foreach on each explode but nothing is working for me

```
$str='ID=62981155;IT=OV80419674-62981155_1_3;OD=15.4;|ID=62981157;IT=OV80419674-62981157_1_3;OD=3.1;|ID=62981159;IT=OV80419674-62981159_1_3;OD=8.13;|';


$array = explode(';|',$str);

foreach($array as $key => $val) 
{
  $v = explode(";",$val);
  foreach($v as $v1)
  {
    $v2= explode("=",$v1);
    foreach($v2 as $k => $s)
    {
    $u[] = $s;  
    }
        
          
  }
}

echo json_encode($u);
```

the result im geting now:
["ID","62981155","IT","OV80419674-62981155_1_3","OD","15.4","ID","62981157","IT","OV80419674-62981157_1_3","OD","3.","ID","62981159","IT","OV80419674-62981159_1_3","OD","8.13",""]

the expected results are:
[{"ID":62981155,"IT":"OV80419674-62981155_1_3","OD":15.4},{"ID":62981157,"IT":"OV80419674-62981157_1_3","OD":3.1},{"ID":62981159,"IT":"OV80419674-62981159_1_3","OD":8.13}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've built up the data in two levels, `$out` is the overall content and `$u` is each individual set of details (which is reset on each loop).

Notice that on the inner loop where you split it by `=`, this will return a key and a value.  This is used to set the associative array instead of just adding each value to an array...

```
$array = explode(';|',$str);
$array = array_filter($array);
$out = [];
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    $u = [];
    $v = explode(";",$val);
    foreach($v as $v1)
    {
        list($key, $value) = explode("=",$v1);
        $u[$key] = $value;
    }
    $out[] = $u;
}

echo json_encode($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the second explode gives you a pair like "KEY=VALUE", the third explode already gives you what you need: KEY and VALUE. There is no need to run in a loop, you can use [list](https://www.php.net/list) to extract both values at once

```
<?php

$str='ID=62981155;IT=OV80419674-62981155_1_3;OD=15.4;|ID=62981157;IT=OV80419674-62981157_1_3;OD=3.1;|ID=62981159;IT=OV80419674-62981159_1_3;OD=8.13;|';

$array = explode(';|', $str);

$u = [];
foreach($array as $key => $val) 
{
  if (empty($val)) {
    continue;
  }

  $tmp = [];
  foreach(explode(";", $val) as $v1)
  {
    list($k, $s) = explode("=", $v1);
    $tmp[$k] = $s; 
  } 
  $u[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($u);
```

this prints

> [{"ID":"62981155","IT":"OV80419674-62981155_1_3","OD":"15.4"},{"ID":"62981157","IT":"OV80419674-62981157_1_3","OD":"3.1"},{"ID":"62981159","IT":"OV80419674-62981159_1_3","OD":"8.13"}]

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to parse the string then loop the match.
In the loop I look for `|` as first character to determine when to move to the next group.

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?)\=(.*?);/", $str, $match);
//var_dump($match);
$i = 0;
foreach($match[1] as $key => $m){
    if($m[0] == "|"){
        $i++;
        $u[$i][substr($m,1)] = $match[2][$key];
    }else{
        $u[$i][$m] = $match[2][$key];
    }
}
echo json_encode($u);
```

https://3v4l.org/S8hKW

Answer (score 0):

You can cut down on the total number of explosions and loops if you format the text into something that PHP can parse natively.  By converting segments into valid URL querystring format, you can leverage `parse_str()`.  This only requires `;` to become `&` and for the trailing pipe to be removed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2nUaO))

```
$str = 'ID=62981155;IT=OV80419674-62981155_1_3;OD=15.4;|ID=62981157;IT=OV80419674-62981157_1_3;OD=3.1;|ID=62981159;IT=OV80419674-62981159_1_3;OD=8.13;|';

$result = [];
foreach (explode('|', rtrim(strtr($str, ';', '&'), '|')) as $set) {
    parse_str($set, $result[]);
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Otherwise, just do all of the explosions and nested loops and use array destructuring to populate the result array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a9dvd))

```
$result = [];
foreach (explode('|', rtrim($str, '|')) as $i => $set) {
    foreach (explode(';', rtrim($set, ';')) as $pair) {
        [$k, $result[$i][$k]] = explode('=', $pair);
    }
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output (from either script):

```
[
    {
        "ID": 62981155,
        "IT": "OV80419674-62981155_1_3",
        "OD": 15.4
    },
    {
        "ID": 62981157,
        "IT": "OV80419674-62981157_1_3",
        "OD": 3.1
    },
    {
        "ID": 62981159,
        "IT": "OV80419674-62981159_1_3",
        "OD": 8.13
    }
]
```